# Parse Elliptic Curve PEM certificate with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, pem, ecdsa

I'd like to parse the below certificate using nodeJS. It is a Hyperledger Fabric certificate using ECDSA. I've tried node-forge but it doesn't support ECC (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/116).

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
MIICKjCCAdCgAwIBAgIRANez5iZg7HjAPv3jEqpTzGgwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwczEL MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG cmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMTE2Nh Lm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMjAwOTE1MTY1ODAwWhcNMzAwOTEzMTY1ODAw WjBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMN U2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEOMAwGA1UECxMFYWRtaW4xHzAdBgNVBAMMFkFkbWluQG9y ZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAARelGSQYlaf khorFSFeWLOjtxVsNlQB0sZBYhEVhqhqnEnJGxa4YJ+wLg6lc7ssYuJNrU1JGba7 lB3HZvHts9+Io00wSzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADArBgNV HSMEJDAigCDHGn/NTq1dt3sUaasmpGS+ZuklWO6uLS7KnJRPkOwwbzAKBggqhkjO PQQDAgNIADBFAiEA2gESuA96ivKNLqBj07gpk2akypZwFEBcgW8Fv36g4kMCIDtr kOkQzcVu4f8uIQqQj+3Gf232J5tFc1rB2WYPwZeL                        
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several other libraries out there which you can use:

- PKI.js
- @ampretia/x509 (actually used in the fabric-sdk-node)
- jsrsasign

to name a few.